# How to Merge Identical Rows with different column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have a table like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
| Job | Class | Employee | PayType | Hours |
| 212     A      John         1        20  |
| 212     A      John         2        10  |
| 911     C      Rebekah      1        15  |
| 911     C      Rebekah      2        10  |
--------------------------------------------
```

I want to convert this table so i can get following output

```
------------------------------------
| Job | Class | Employee | OT | ST |
| 212 |   A   | John     | 20 | 10 |
| 911 |   C   | Rebekah  | 15 | 10 |
------------------------------------
```

Here I've set 1 for OT and 2 for ST

Comment: You tagged this with pivot so I suppose you know this is what needs to be done - did you have some problem with pivoting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    job,
    class,
    employee
    sum(case when paytype = 1 then hours else 0 end) ot,
    sum(case when paytype = 2 then hours else 0 end) st
from mytable
group by
    jobs,
    class,
    employee
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `PIVOT TABLE`:

```
select 
   Job,
   Class,
   Employee,
   [1] as OT, 
   [2] as ST from
   (
      select * from test2
   ) as t
   pivot
   (
      sum([Hours])
      for paytype in([1],[2])
   ) as pvt;
```